# Can't edit Navigation bar title when duplicating UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a `UIViewController` that I created in my Storyboard. I have another `UIViewController` which I want to look exactly the same but with the Navigation Bar Title changed. Therefore, I did CMD + D (Duplicate in XCode) to get the same UIViewController. I have both hooked up to separate UINavigationControllers. However, I don't seem to be able to edit it. Here are some photos for demonstration:

[image: Title in which I can edit]

Versus

[image: Title I cannot edit]

In the first image, I click on the word `Editable Title` and can edit it. However, on the second image, clicking on the word `Title` does nothing. It remains as title. I know I can change it programmatically, but I just want to see if I can change it via the `StoryBoard` just for consistency purposes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I've tried to edit the Title value to something like "Test Title" in the `Attributes Inspector` to the desired title but it still shows up as the text "Title"

Comment: Try using cmd+c and cmd+v. I'm pretty sure you can edit that on the editor on the right.

Comment: @Aryaman I've tried to edit the Title value to something like "Test Title" in the Attributes Inspector to the desired title but it still shows up as the text "Title".

Comment: Can you change the title in the first one?

Comment: @Aryaman yes I can change the title for the first one but not the second one.

Comment: Then its very easy just copy paste the first one after changing the text. Make sure to copy fully!!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old and unresponsive question, like solved by now by the OP but it is better to keep it answered with the actual solution for the future readers.

This is likely an Xcode bug but title can be changed in Document Outline area and directly selecting the navigation item and change the title in Attributes panel.